# Scala, ZIO - how to test if effect returned success?

Tags: scala, scalatest, zio

I have a simple test code which check mocked service:

```
 runtime.unsafeRun(service.run.forkDaemon)
    eventually(Timeout(Span(5, Seconds)), Interval(Span(1, Seconds))) {
      verify(someMockResult).create(any[String], any[String])
    }
```

The `service` returns `Task[Done]`. It works ok, but I would like to check also if this `unsafeRun` returns `succeed`. I tried to do it like this:

```
runtime.unsafeRun(service.run.forkDaemon) shouldBe succeed
```

or:

```
val result = runtime.unsafeRun(service.run.forkDaemon)
   eventually(Timeout(Span(5, Seconds)), Interval(Span(1, Seconds))) {
      result shouldBe succeed
   }
```

But it does not work. Is there any way to check if effect result is succeed?

Comment: what is `succeed`? Do you mean that you want to check that your service returns something that was constructed by `zio.ZIO.succeed` function?

Comment: `succeed` is an assertion from scalatest. I want to check if my result end with success, not failure.

Comment: you misunderstood the meaning of `org.scalatest.Succeed` (which is aliased by `succeed`). It needed only in case when you need to end up body of a function with `Assertion` type. It is equal to `assert(true)` basically. It is not primitive to test something.

Comment: Ok, so do you know how I can check what I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you misunderstood the meaning of `org.scalatest.Succeed` (which is aliased by `succeed`). It is needed only when you need to end up the body of a function with the `Assertion` type. It is equal to `assert(true)` basically. It is not an assertion that actually tests something.

If I understood right that you want to check the execution of your `testTask` that we define as:

```
val testTask: Task[Done] = service.run.forkDaemon
```

The problem in your code that `val res = runtime.unsafeRun(testTask)` executes it **synchronously**. This means that this line of code evaluates with two possible outcomes: 1) it successfully executes `testTask` and assigns the result to the `res` variable, or 2) execution of `testTask` fails, and it throws an exception.

So, basically, if there is no exception, it is succeeded.

Another way to check this more conveniently is to evaluate it to `Future` with `runtime.unsafeRunToFuture` and then assert that `future` is eventually succeeded. You can do it with, for example, like this:

```
assert(
  future.value match { 
    case Some(Success(_)) => true 
    case _ => false
  }
)
```